# Autocomplete doesn't seem to work with ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, autocomplete

I am trying to implement autocomplete on a textfield for search which has the following code in my view file index.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag search_path, method: :get do %>
<p>
<%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query], :id => 'autocomplete'  %>
<%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

I included the following method in my model

```
def self.query_matches(term) 
tire.search do
    query {string "query:#{term}"}  
end
end
```

and controller is as follows

```
def autocomplete
results = Univ.query_matches(params[:term]) 
render :json => results, :callback => params[:callback] 
end
```

I included the jQuery-ui in application.js file in js folder. However, I don't see autocomplete running in my view.

The jQuery im using for this is as follows

```
jQuery ->
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete ({
source: function(request,response) {
jQuery.ajax({
url: "http://localhost:3000/univ/autocomplete.json",
dataType: "jsonp",
data: {
    term: request.term
},
success: function(data){
var rows: [];
for( var i = 0; i< data.length; i++){
    rows.push({data[i].query,value:data[i].query});
}
response(rows);
}
});
}
});
```

Can anyone suggest where I might be going wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In index.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag search_path, method: :get do %>
 <p>
  <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query], :id => 'autocomplete', data: {autocomplete_source: univ_autocomplete_url}  %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>
 </p>
<% end %>
```

In univ_controller as:

```
def autocomplete
 results = Univ.where("field_name LIKE ?", "#{params[:term]}%")
 render json: results.map(&:field_name)
end
```

In application.js as:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
    source: $( "#autocomplete" ).data('autocomplete-source')
 });
});
```

If field is searched on typing two character in the form then it should be written as or it can be changed as required:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    source: $( "#autocomplete" ).data('autocomplete-source')
 });
});
```

Add in routes.rb:-

```
get "univ/autocomplete"
```

**Note:-** There should be a controller named as **univ** OR add this **autocomplete method** in a controller and check for the routes. Then change the routes **univ_autocomplete_url** with the new route in **data: {autocomplete_source: univ_autocomplete_url}**.

If the **autocomplete method** is added in other controller then change the **routes.rb** as:-

```
get "controller_name/autocomplete"
```

Comment: I get an error as 
undefined local variable or method 'univ_autocomplete_url'. Do I have to include a view named as autocomplete?

Comment: check the routes for /univ/autocomplete which you have used in ajax in the line url: "http://localhost:3000/univ/autocomplete.json", and change it that way.

Comment: I checked my routes I don't see any routes matching the univ/autocomplete.json . Earlier I was trying to implement an example so I'm unsure where im doing wrong. Any idea what part of the code has to be updated?

Comment: I updated the changes made in the post. But the search field still doesn't work :/ Sorry that I included it in your answer